# c# / LINQ .Select in Java (alternative)

Tags: java, c#, arrays, linq

In C# I have the following code:

```
string[] exampleStrings = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');          // C#
int[] exampleInts = exampleStrings.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

The `.Select` can also be like this: `.Select(x => int.Parse(x))`

That way I get really quickly an `int[]`. 
I started learning Java a few days ago and I am yet to get used to it. 
I have the following code in Java:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);                            // Java
String[] javaStrings = scan.nextLine().split(" ");
```

And I would like to convert this `String[] javaStrings` into `int[] foo`. If there is no way to do it like in C# I think then a loop will maybe be the only way.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Java streams you can write

```
int[] n = Arrays.stream(javaStrings).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```